# Stored procedure causing syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have written this stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetCuisines]
    @RestaurantID INT ,
    @CuisineID NVARCHAR(200)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @sql = 'SELECT  CuisineID, CuisineName
    FROM    dbo.Cuisine1
    WHERE   CuisineID IN (
            SELECT  dbo.Dishes1.CuisineID
            FROM    dbo.Dishes1
            WHERE   DishID IN ( SELECT  DishID
                                FROM    dbo.RestaurantDish
                                WHERE   RestaurantID = '
        + CAST(@RestaurantID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + ' ) )'                                    
    IF @CuisineID <> ''
        BEGIN
            SET @sql += 'AND Cuisine1.CuisineID IN('
                + CAST(@CuisineID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) +')'
        END
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql; 
END
```

I am using 3 tables with their columns listed below:

**Dishes1**

```
   DishID
   DishName
   CuisineID
   Price
```

**Cuisine1**

```
   CuisineID
   CuisineName
   Type
   DateCreated
   DateModified
   DateDeleted
```

**RestaurantDish**

```
RestaurantDishID
RestaurantID
DishID
```

but my stored procedure gives me syntax error on this line:

```
    SET @sql += 'AND Cuisine1.CuisineID IN('+ CAST(@CuisineID AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) +')'
```

it says:

> *incorrect syntax near "+"*

Can somebody guide me? Does the SQL Server version have something to do with this?

Comment: Well, which **version** of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: also, have you heard of joins?

Comment: yes. i know about joins. what to do with them?

Comment: Do you even need to do the cast; it's already an NVARCHAR? Also, your primary keys should not be maximum length strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using is only valid on SQL Server 2008 and above. On SQL Server 2005, you'll have to change:

```
SET @sql += ...
```

To:

```
SET @sql = @sql + ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no need to use dynamic SQL here - so don't ! Also: prefer **JOIN** over subqueries - joins are typically faster, and quite frankly - code is **much easier** to read!

Just use:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetCuisines]
    @RestaurantID INT ,
    @CuisineID NVARCHAR(200)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT  
        c.CuisineID, c.CuisineName
    FROM    
        dbo.Cuisine1 c
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Dishes1 d ON d.CuisineID = c.CuisineID
    INNER JOIN
        dbo.Restaurant1 r ON r.DishID = d.DishID
    WHERE  
        r.RestaurantID = @RestaurantID
        AND (@CuisineID = '' OR c.CuisineID = @CuisineID)
END
```

And Aaron Bertrand is absolutely right, of course - this only works if you pass in a single `CuisineID` as string.

If your `@CuisineID` parameter contains multiple values then you need something like this instead:

```
    WHERE  
        r.RestaurantID = @RestaurantID
        AND (@CuisineID = '' OR c.CuisineID IN dbo.Split(@CuisineID))
```

Using a function `Split` you can split up a comma-separated list of ID's into a table variable and use the `IN` operator to match to a list of possible values.

Comment: Only true if `@CuisineID` is actually an integer - I suspect it might be a comma separated list of IDs.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: you're absolutely right - but it should at least steer the OP in the right direction - I hope! :-)

Answer (score 0):

are you perhaps passing in a comma delimited string??
If so, there is a better way to handle this, see here:

http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/10/26/quick-t-sql-to-parse-a-delimited-string/